# How to configure Asus Xonar DS on HP Compaq Elite 8300 CMT to remain the default sound card in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have installed an *Asus Xonar DS 7.1* sound card on *HP Compaq Elite 8300 CMT*. It worked fine until a couple of days when there is no sound any more. I have to manually select the sound card using `alsamixer`. After restart it all goes to default and I have to do this again.
I have installed pulse audio control to select the right combination to make the sound work. Sometimes it works using analog surround 5.1 output + analog stereo input and sometimes it works using analog surround 7.1 output + analog stereo input. The configuration has to be selected every time I listen to a new mp3 or even I have to change the video from youtube.

I have read a lot the last couple of days. I have clean installed Ubuntu 18.04. All worked fine for a few days. 
Please help me configure the Asus sound card to stay as default.
This is what `pacmd list-sinks` shows:

```
3 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC221 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC221 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7f30000 irq 29"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1e20"
        device.product.name = "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC221"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0221,103c3396,00100003"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:

        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
  * index: 9
    name: <alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9049
    volume: front-left: 41564 /  63% / -11,87 dB,   front-right: 41564 /  63% / -11,87 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 55,81 ms
    max request: 8 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 11
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 46,00 ms; range is 46,00 .. 1837,50 ms
    card: 3 <alsa_card.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00>
    module: 26
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Audio Device"
        alsa.long_card_name = "C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Audio Device at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.4:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/sound/card3"
        udev.id = "usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "0d8c"
        device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0012"
        device.product.name = "USB Audio Device"
        device.serial = "C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device"
        device.string = "front:3"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "USB Audio Device Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.components = "USB0d8c:0012"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
    index: 10
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_02_01.0.analog-surround-71>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   front-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   rear-left: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   rear-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   front-center: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   lfe: 37081 /  57% / -14,84 dB,   side-left: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   side-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 12
    sample spec: s16le 8ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe,side-left,side-right
                 Surround 7.1
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 1486,08 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_02_01.0>
    module: 9
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "Multichannel"
        alsa.id = "Multichannel"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "Xonar DS"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Asus Virtuoso 66 at 0xd000, irq 21"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_virtuoso"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:02:01.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:02:01.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "13f6"
        device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics Inc"
        device.product.id = "8788"
        device.product.name = "CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio] (Virtuoso 66 (Xonar DS))"
        device.string = "surround71:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "1048576"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "1048576"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-surround-71"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Surround 7.1"
        device.description = "CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio] (Virtuoso 66 (Xonar DS)) Analog Surround 7.1"
        alsa.mixer_name = "AV200"
        alsa.components = "WM8776 WM8766 AV200"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

    active port: <analog-output>
```

Comment: Do you actually use the built-in and the USB devices?

Comment: Did you set the device and profile as the default in system settings (`gnome-control-center audio input` if you can't find it). If yes and/or if that doesn't help, could you please [edit] your question to include the content of `~/.pulse/default.pa` or, in its absence, `/etc/pulse/default.pa`? Thanks. Other than that I agree with CL that the simplest way is probably to disable all other audio devices (in BIOS or by disconnecting them) if you don't use them to avoid their prioritisation by PulseAudio.

Comment: That should have been `gnome-control-center audio output` of course.